In MAUI the Content.KeyUp cannot capture pressing Enter key
In MAUI, using KeyUp I can capture all the key pressing, but not pressing Enter key. Here is the code:
window.Content.KeyUp += (s,e){
   //do something
}

If I press the Enter key of keyboard, nothing will happen. If I press other keys, the KeyUp handler will be triggered.
What caused the issue? How can I fix this? Any suggestion?
Thanks!

You can also refer to the official doc: UIElement.KeyUp Event.

You can try the following code, it can capture pressing Enter key.
public partial class NewPage1 : ContentPage
{
    public NewPage1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnHandlerChanged()
    {
        base.OnHandlerChanged();
#if WINDOWS
        Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Window window = (Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Window)App.Current.Windows.First<Window>().Handler.PlatformView;
        window.Content.KeyUp += Content_KeyUp;
#endif
    }
 
#if WINDOWS
    private void Content_KeyUp(object sender, Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Input.KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var a = e.Key.ToString();
    }
#endif

}

Here is the effect.
